# Angular: switch inside repeat, memory problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I'm building a `tr` with different `td` *components* inside.

There are many different `td` *components* available and only a few will be rendered.

```
<tr ng-repeat='row in rowlist'>
  <td ng-repeat='columnType in columnsThatShouldBeDisplayed' ng-switch='columnType'>
    <colA ng-switch-when='typeA'></colA>
    <colB ng-switch-when='typeB'></colB>
    <colC ng-switch-when='typeC'></colC>
    // and so on..
  <td>
</tr>
```

This takes a lot of memory. It seems like all my components is constructed, but only one is displayed for each iteration.

What is the correct way of doing this?
Tips on how to go around the problem and doing it another way?

Comment: Can I ask for a simple thing? Could you provide a simple table structure that you are trying to build? Image, HTML, everything will be fine

Comment: ng-switch-when does remove the unmatched switch content from DOM, so the final DOM would be only be minimal needed stuff. So it doesnt take lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

**you have to include the ng-switch as an attribute of the repeat element**

```
<div ng-controller="formPersonalInfoController">
    <form role="form">
        <div ng-repeat="Country in Countries" class="animate-switch-container" ng-switch on="Country.name">
            <div>
                <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="Andorra">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="text-info">{{ Country.name }} :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <textarea id="{{Country.Id}}" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ Country.name }}"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-default>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="text-info">{{ Country.name | uppercase }} :</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="{{Country.Id}}" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ Country.name }}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```